# Recovering ext4 superblock error

Tags: disk, postgresql

Server crashed due to huge posgresql ram usage. After restart, the disk which located postgresql data did not mount due to superblock error.

I created new volume from aws console for restoring that partition.

**1** - I cloned the corrupted disk to the new disk via ddrestore like;

`ddrescue -v —force /dev/nvme1n1 /dev/nvme3n1 /tmp.log`

**2** - the fsck result

> ext2fs_open2: Bad magic number in super-block
> fsck.ext2: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...
> fsck.ext2: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/nvme1n1
>
> The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid
> ext2/ext3/ext4 filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really
> contains an ext2/ext3/ext4 filesystem (and not swap or ufs or
> something else), then the superblock is corrupt, and you might try
> running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
> e2fsck -b 8193   or
> e2fsck -b 32768

**3** - I found backup superblocks list with

`sudo mke2fs -n /dev/nvme1n1`

Results :

> Creating filesystem with 73242187 4k blocks and 18317312 inodes
> Filesystem UUID: 5b950060-1755-46b4-bef0-4a76e721f668
> Superblock backups stored on blocks:
> 32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736, 1605632, 2654208,
> 4096000, 7962624, 11239424, 20480000, 23887872, 71663616

**4** - I tried all of superblocks with ;

```
sudo e2fsck -b 32768 /dev/nvme1n1
```

it did not work for me. the other part(which is root volume) on the same ssd works fine.

Can you help me?

Comment: You could use R-Studio Undelete. It costs money but it's totally worth it.

Comment: 1) Did you get any errors ot warnings on your `ddrescue` run? 2) You name a data base overload as cause of the problem, but you treat it as hard disk crash. Actually, it's hard to image how the cashing data base should mess up *all* superblocks. 3) Have a look at the  superblock locations with a hex editor: Maybe you can find some hints on what really happened. Is everything overwritten with 0x00 or 0xFF or is the partition table entry defect or …